# Reading dynamically allocated structure's field yeilds segmentation fault

Tags: c++, struct, new-operator

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef struct _MOVIE {
    int ROW;
    int COL;
    string name;
} MOVIE;

void createData(MOVIE **MOVIES, int &moviesCnt) {
    ifstream fin("movies.txt");

    if (!fin.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error on opening file\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    fin >> moviesCnt;
    MOVIES = new MOVIE *[moviesCnt];

    for (int i = 0; i < moviesCnt; i++) {
        if (fin.eof()) {
            cerr << "Error on file format\n";
            exit(1);
        }
        MOVIES[i] = new MOVIE; // must allocate mem for struct...

        fin >> ws; // Buffer clear
        getline(fin, (MOVIES[i])->name);

        fin >> (MOVIES[i])->ROW >> (MOVIES[i])->COL;
    }
}

int main() {
    MOVIE **MOVIES;
    int moviesCnt;

    createData(MOVIES, moviesCnt);

    cout << (MOVIES[0])->ROW;
}
```

And this is the given txt file

```
3
Lala Land
5 3
Fast and Furious
5 5
Ship-victory
6 5
```

So what I tried to do is
Make an array of pointer of structure and each pointer of structure points a structure of given data.

As `MOVIES` are dynamically allocated by `new` operator, so it should be read in `main` function but `Segmentation fault` occurs.

Using `gdb` to debug, and it says

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0040164a in main () at test.cpp:44
44          cout << (MOVIES[0])->ROW;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please read on pass-by value vs pass-by reference: your `createData` function modifies a copy of passed in pointer. Hence, those changes would not be visible outside of it.

Comment: With modern C++, there are much better alternatives to using `new`.  In C++ (that isn't interoperating with C), there is no reason to use `typedef struct _MOVIE { ... } MOVIE;`.  Rather than use `MOVIE** MOVIES`, I recommend `std::vector<MOVIE>`.  Rather than have in/out parameters, I recommend only having in parameters, and have results returned via `return`.

Answer (score 1):

Normal arguments of functions in C++ are *copies* of what are passed, so the assignment in funtion `createData`

```
    MOVIES = new MOVIE *[moviesCnt];
```

will NOT have any effects to the variable `MOVIE **MOVIES;` in the function `main()`.

To have this modify what is passed, you should use *references*.

Add `&` before the argument name `MOVIES` to make the argument a reference.

```
void createData(MOVIE **&MOVIES, int &moviesCnt) {
```